# C++ Problem with handling a state between two classes in a hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, architecture

### Problem Description

Consider the following class hierarchy. Concrete templated class A, templated abstract class B and an interface C, with `A <-- B <-- C`. Consider that B has a function declaration

```cpp
virtual std::optional<T> foo() const  = 0;
```

and c has a function declaration

```cpp
virtual bar() = 0;
```

both of which are defined in A appropriately.

There exists somewhere in the code a list of objects B, over which we call `foo()`, and there exists a list of C* pointers over which we call `bar()`.

For a minimal example:

### Example and My Issue

```cpp
class A <typename T> : public B <T>
{
public: 
    std::optional<T> foo() const override { /*...*/ };
    bar() override { /*...*/ };

    // ...
};

class B <typename T> : public C
{
public: 
    virtual std::optional<T> foo() const = 0;

    // ...
}

class C
{
public: 
    virtual bar() = 0;
}
```

The issue I am having is that I want to add a boolean state over this small hierarchy. Particularly, I have the following requirements

1. I need a boolean state `m_isInteresting` over the object represented by this hierarchy.
2. I don't want `m_isInteresting` state it to be in A (for decoupling reasons).
3. I want `foo()` to set `m_isInteresting = true;`.
4. I want `bar()` to set `m_isInteresting = false;`.

How can I achieve this?

### Things I have tried

- I tried to create a decorator wrapper around C with the `m_isInteresting` member and the appropriate accessors, with a method forward of `bar()`, in which I call C's `bar()` function and set the class member `m_isInteresting` to false, but then I can't set the member to true because `foo()` is down the class hierarchy.
- I tried to move `foo()`'s declaration to C (while keeping it's definition in A), but this is very difficult because the function returns a `std::optional<T>` and well, C is not templated; a derived class's function signature must match that of the base class.
- I have thought of making decorator classes for both B and C with `m_isInteresting` shared between them, but held externally, but this is getting ugly and complicated.

There must be something that I am missing here.

Comment: What you claim to be a [mre] is not.  The code you show [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/K6nqPKrYE), for many reasons.  I also recommend that you not take question downvotes personally.  They simply mean that this question may not currently be a good fit for Stack Overflow (usefulness, clarity, etc.)

Comment: If you would care for feedback. As a random SO user, interested in C++ question, I saw the title, found the title overly generic. Then a problem description showing an involved setup (why those classes, why the inheritance, why the optional?) and I thought "KISS principle FFS!", then a bunch of requirements. I didn't feel like upvoting, to say the least

Comment: It seems like you're missing something in the architecture. Classes are meant to isolate state, with a controlled interface, not share state. So maybe you want a third state object that they update? Maybe you really want to subclass A to handle the new state? Maybe you don't actually need to "decouple" A (for whatever reasons)? Really too many unknowns in your question for me to guess where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code fulfils your requirements. You can put `m_isInteresting` inside the `C` class and mark it **protected** for the subclasses to be able to access it. You can then refer to it as `this->m_isInteresting` in the subclasses.

```cpp
#include "optional"

class C {
protected:
    bool m_isInteresting = false;
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class B: public C {
public:
    virtual std::optional<T> foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class A: public B<T> {
public:
    std::optional<T> foo() override {
        this->m_isInteresting = true;
        return {};
    }
    void bar() override {
        this->m_isInteresting = false;
    }
};
```